# Suppose V is a vector space and W1, W2, W3 are subspaces of V such that W2 is a subspace of W1. Show that W1 ∩ (W2 + W3) = W2 + (W1 ∩ W3).

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $W_1$, $W_2$, $W_3$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $W_2$ is a subspace
of $W_1$. Show that $$W_1 \cap (W_2 + W_3) = W_2 + (W_1 \cap W_3).$$
Can I do the following :
$W_1 \cap (W_2 + W_3)=W_1\cap W_2+W_1\cap W_3$ but as $W_2$ is a subspace of $W_1$ , $W_1 \cap W_2=W_2$.

Is this proof correct? If not can you show a correct proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not right. $W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)$ is not generally equal to $W_1\cap W_2+W_1\cap W_3$. Consider $W_1, W_2, W_3$ - three different subspaces of dimension $1$ in a vector space $V$ of dimension $2$. (Imagine three different lines through the origin in a plane). There you have $W_1\cap W_2=W_1\cap W_3=\{0\}$ but $W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)=W_1\cap V=W_1$.

Of course, the equality *is* true when $W_2\subset W_1$ - but this is pretty much equivalent to your question, so your argument would be circular (i.e. you would be assuming the very thing you are asked here to prove).

**Note**: I wrote this answer before you changed the question from "check if my proof is right" to "check if my proof is right, and if not, show me the right proof". It the meantime there have been useful hints in other answers, which I won't repeat. The basic idea is - $W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)=W_2+(W_1\cap W_3)$ is an equality of *sets*, so you can approach it as any other set equality: suppose $x$ is in the LHS, prove that it belongs to RHS and vice versa. One direction should be a bit easier than the other. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do like that, because it would require to prove that
$$
W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)=(W_1\cap W_2)+(W_1\cap W_3)
$$
which unfortunately is generally false.

Suppose $v\in W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)$; then, by definition, there are $x\in W_2$ and $y\in W_3$ such that $v=x+y$. Since $W_2\subseteq W_1$, we have $x\in W_1$, so $y=v-x\in W_1$, which implies $y\in W_1\cap W_3$. Hence $v=x+y\in W_2+(W_1\cap W_3)$.

This proves that $W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)\subseteq W_2+(W_1\cap W_3)$.

Now prove the converse inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer**

No you can't do as you did, because with vecteur space, $\cap$ is not distributive with respect to $+$. So, let $v\in W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)$. then there are $u\in W_2$ and $w\in W_3$ s.t. $$v=u+w.$$ Now, $$w=v-u\in W_1,$$
and thus $w\in W_1\cap W_3$. Therefore $v\in W_2+W_1\cap W_3.$ I let you prove the converse inclusion.